# How to set Android versionCode using xml resource

Tags: android, build.gradle

In Android build.gradle i wanted to set the `versionCode` like this but it´s not working. The `versionName` is working however.

```
defaultConfig {
   versionCode "@integer/application_version_code"
   versionName "@string/application_version_name"
}
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43682571/6296561)

Answer (score 0):

I added a @integer reference to versionCode, and this is the error I got(reproduction):

```
Error:(10, 0) Could not find method versionCode() for arguments [@integer/code]
```

From what I understand, this is because the argument passed is a String. versionCode = integer, not string.

Moving the versionName and -Code to the Manifest works fine for versionName, but versionCode shows this line

> The android:versionCode cannot be a resource URL, it must be a literal integer

(when the manifest tag contains:

```
android:versionName="@string/name"
android:versionCode="@integer/code"
```

)

So from what I understand of research, you cannot set versionCode using a resource URL, it has to be defined in either build.gradle or the manifest as a literal integer.

Further, it looks like using @string on versionName is not fine either. It has to be declared as a literal string. Meaning no resource URL there either.

### In conclusion

You cannot use a @integer resource on versionCode. You cannot use @string on versionName. Define them as a literal [integer/string] in build.gradle or the manifest.